Old anime on YouTube where a young boy would gain superpowers when he wore a golden necklace
When I was small I remember watching an old anime on YouTube where a young boy would gain superpowers when he wore a golden necklace.
I remember one episode when the villain in the anime made a portal and kids were asleep levitating into it but the protagonist wore the necklace so he was awake.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Approximately what year would you have watched this?

It astounds me that YouTube is old enough for you to have watched it when you were little...

@Valorum You're forgetting that the OP might be 10, for all we know.

@Daemonic Of course, YouTube is 19 years old.

@PaulD.Waite Yes? Sorry, I don't see what you're getting at.

@Daemonic Well I’m saying the OP could be like 22, and still have watched this thing on YouTube when little.

@PaulD.Waite Oh, yeah that makes sense.
